# How to print multiple gt tables in a quarto chunk?

Tags: r, quarto, gt

I have a list of `gt` tables I'd like to display.  I seem to recall in RMarkdown, I could use a `walk(tabs, print)` statement inside a chunk with with `results = "asis"` chunk option for this to work.

I can't figure out how to do this in Quarto?  Any advice?

Here is what I tried, but it fails to render.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: source
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
df <- mtcars[1:5, 1:2] 
tab <- gt(df)
```

```{r}
#| results: asis
rep(list(tab), 3) %>%
  walk(print)
```
````

The error in rendering is as follows:

```
    Error running filter C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Quarto/share/filters/quarto-pre/quarto-pre.lua:
.../Programs/Quarto/share/filters/quarto-pre/quarto-pre.lua:2555: attempt to concatenate a nil value (local 'v')
stack traceback:
    .../Programs/Quarto/share/filters/quarto-pre/quarto-pre.lua:2562: in function <.../Programs/Quarto/share/filters/quarto-pre/quarto-pre.lua:2560>
```

Comment: Would you elaborate on how "it fails to render"? Because I am getting the tables (three tables) by running your code.

Comment: Interesting...are you running or rendering?  Run works for me, but not render.

Comment: Rendering. Can you specify the quarto version you are using to render the posted example?

Comment: Sure.  `packageVersion("quarto")` returns `1.2`.

Comment: `packageVersion("quarto")` is returning the version of `quarto` R package.  You can check the quarto version using `quarto::quarto_version()`.

Comment: Result of `quarto_version` is ‘1.2.313’

Comment: Okay then I would recommend updating the quarto (the current stable released version is 1.3.310)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the quarto CLI software, the quarto package, rmarkdown, and knitr, and the error went away.  Appreciate everyone who chimed in.

Answer (score 2):

Quarto likes it when you feed it `gt` tables `as_raw_html`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: source
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
df <- mtcars[1:5, 1:2] 
tab <- gt(df)

```

```{r}
#| results: asis
rep(list(tab), 3) %>%
  map(as_raw_html) |> 
  walk(print) 
```
````

ftr I was getting the same message you were even after I updated quarto.